# How to insert NULL instead on nan into sql server from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have pandas data frame from Excel file .While inserting the DF to SQL server missing values are inserting as "nan" for few columns . I want this values should be NULL instead on nan .
For few columns it is insert NULL bit for few values updating as "nan" .
what is wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Database treats `NaN` as `null` itself. Maybe some `NaN's` in your code are `string` because of which it gets written as `Nan` in DB. You need to convert all string Nan as `np.nan`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Can you please tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you show an example of your DataFrame?

Comment: STATE ZIPCD PRIMPHONE  H1045-001   H1045-005 
AL 35802 747474747  
FL 33016 737373  
FL 32207 37337373

@Gerd